# Can this sentence be said?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-choice, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

If not, please tell me the alternative.

> These types of issues cannot be haphazardly assigned opinions/judgements/views to them
>   without first taking a methodical approach to studying them.

I am not sure that the word "**assigned**" is appropriate here. Can it be replaced with "**given**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

I recommend:

> **One should study these matters before forming an opinion.**

---

I see the following issues with the original sentence construction.

- **Double-negatives**. Writers should avoid them.
- **Redundancy**. The writer refers to "types of issues" 3 times.
- **Passive voice**. Writers should choose active voice.

These factors combined in the original sentence to make an awkward expression of the writer's idea.

---

#### Reasoning and references

The above "issues" are not **rules** as much as they are generally accepted **guides** studied and used by many professional writers. I refer you to the classic text on the subject: [**The Elements of Style** by Strunk and White](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style).

English is a flexible language. There are many ways to express ideas that are technically proper English but might not be the most effective way to communicate. Guidelines set forth in *The Elements of Style* bridge much of the gap between what is **correct** English and what is **effective** English.

Comment: There's no actual rule about any of those three things... that may be your preference but, depending on the type of writing, they're all perfectly acceptable, if not (in the case of passive voice) preferable.

Comment: @Catija. I agree. These are not **rules** as much as they are generally accepted **guides** used by professional writers. I refer you to the classic text on the subject: [**The Elements of Style** by Strunk and White](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style). English is a flexible language. There are many ways to express ideas that are technically proper English but might not be the most effective way to communicate using the English language. Guidelines in *The Elements of Style* bridge much of the gap between what is **correct** English and what is **effective** English.

Comment: Don't refer me to them... you're the one making assertions without supporting them. If you're going to make statements in your answer, explain them and cite some references. :) That's how you write a good answer. Telling a learner "don't do this" without explaining why to not do it, doesn't really help them.

Comment: That book is helpful. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say none, because one does not give their judgements or opinions to an issue, one gives their opinions and judgements to an audience regarding an issue, even if you yourself are the audience. Just think about it logically, you can't give your opinion on a book to the book, or give your opinion on a crime to the crime.

Furthermore, you're using "without first taking a methodical approach" in conjunction with "haphazardly", instead of cancelling "haphazardly" and providing the correct substitute. So essentially what the language says in your example is that it's okay to arrive at a haphazard opinion/view/judgement once you've methodically studied the issue. This of course is self contradictory because you're no longer taking haphazard action after giving serious disciplined and objective effort.

A better way to speak this would be to say:

> One cannot haphazardly establish judgement or opinion on such issues,
>   but rather must methodically study them and draw conclusions as
>   objectively as possible.

Answer (score 1):

"Issues *have* things assigned to them", not "issues *are* things assigned to them". Also you need to rearrange the words:

These types of issues cannot have opinions/judgements/views assigned to them haphazardly, without first taking a methodical approach to studying them.

You could say "haphazardly assigned to them," but adverbs (haphazardly) usually go after the verb (assigned) not before it.

"Assigned to them" is sort-of-OK, but "applied to them" or "associated with them" might be better. You can't really "give" something to an abstract idea like "an opinion", so "given" doesn't work here.